# How to ignore flasks http 400 exception in Sentry

Tags: flask, sentry

I have setup a flask project in Sentry but have noticed a problem that I need to fix.

Currently if the flask application throws a HTTPException (for example for a validation exception) that exception creates an issue in Sentry. This clutters up the issues since it creates issues even for HTTP 400.

Are there any way to configure Sentry so it ignores all HTTPExceptions with code 4xx but still create Issues for all HTTPExceptions with code 5xx?

Comment: Hi, could you post a small example and tell us which SDK you are using? This sounds like a bug

Answer (score 0):

If I’m not mistaken, Sentry should only send not handled exceptions. So you could setup custom error handlers: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/errorpages/?highlight=error%20handler#error-handlers

If you want to handle all default exceptions you could register an error handler like this:

```
 from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions

 def register_error_handlers(app):
    """ Register error handler for default exceptions """

    for code in default_exceptions:
        app.register_error_handler(code, your_error_handler)
```

where `app` is your flask App instance and `your_error_handler` takes the error as argument and returns a response. So you could filter for the 400 codes in this for loop to only handle 4xx errors.